# Monogdb update function works on terminal but not on metoer server

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here with absolutely no luck.

`db.attendances.update({ _id: 'hRs6LfAqPBmy4ZNuH' }, { $set: { absentParentOrGuardianDate: undefined } })`

If I run this update command in the terminal shell using '**meteor mongo**'  `absentParentOrGuardianDate` is removed from the document, however, if I run the same code, slightly changed for meteor, on the meteor server I get an error.

`Attendances.update({ _id: 'hRs6LfAqPBmy4ZNuH' }, { $set: { absentParentOrGuardianDate: undefined } });`

**The error is:**
`{isClientSafe: true, error: 500, reason: "Internal server error", details: undefined, message: "Internal server error [500]", …}`

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing here.

Comment: Why do you want to set it to undefined?

Perhaps using `{ $unset: { absentParentOrGuarinanDate: '' } }` or `$pull` (if it's related to arrays) operators would be better.

Comment: If I use `$unset I can't add new fields as well, it only removes the field. I've also tried { $unset : { absentParentOrGuardinanDate : '' }, $set : { myNewField : 'test data's }}` but this errors.

Comment: Can you show us the errors on server side? I think the error you post is on client side.

Comment: `name: 'MongoError', errmsg: 'Updating the path \'absentParentOrGuardianDate\' would create a conflict at \'absentParentOrGuardianDate\'' }`

Comment: I think the problem in the error I just posted comes from me trying to $unset then $set the same field. Is this not allowed.

Comment: Yeah, it might not make sense to mongo. If you want to replace the value of `absentParentOrGuardinanDate`, then `$set: { absentPArentOrGuardinanDate: <new value>}` should work.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to do, however, my object sometimes contains undefined fields. This is causing it to break.

Comment: What does "my object sometimes contains undefined fields" mean?
Will `$set: { absentParentOrGuardinanDate: obj.someValue || null } ` help? `|| null` could be replaced with your ideal default value.

Comment: { $set: { fieldOne: undefined, fieldTwo: 'new data', fieldThree: 'Some data', fieldFour: undefined  } }

Comment: And what's your expected end result from that query?

Comment: The undefined fields, if they exist in the document, should be removed and if they have data they should update or insert.

Comment: I think you might need to know the values of fieldOne, ..., fieldFour before update the document. Like, `const updateDoc = {}; if (!fieldOne) updateDoc.$unset = { fieldOne: '' } else updateDoc.$set = { fieldOne: 'new data' }`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following how that would look. Could you show me a full example please

Comment: [MongoDB Manual - $type - Available Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#available-types) mentioned that undefined is deprecated. I'm not sure if it has something to do with this.

Comment: I post an answer so that the code block could present more nicely.

Comment: For anyone else who get's stuck on this. @FlissHou was correct. It is actually related to MongoDB type undefined being deprecated. The solution was to set the element to null.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { _ } from 'meteor/underscore';

const updateDoc = {};
_.each(yourObj, (value, key) => { // I'm using underscore to help loop through the object
  if (value) {
    updateDoc.$set[key] = value;
  } else {
    updateDoc.$unset[key] = value;
  }
});
yourCollection.update(yourSelector, updateDoc);
```